# ContextMenu is not disappearing from ExtJs Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using contextmenu in my ExtJS grid. It's coming correct. My problem is when I am using right click then menu is appearing. Again when I change grid row the context menu is not disappearing.

My code

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function() {
        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            title: 'itemcontextmenu',
            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                data: [
                    {
                        'name': 'Lisa',
                        "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                        "phone": "555-111-1224"
                    }, 
                    {
                        'name': 'Bart',
                        "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                        "phone": "555-222-1234"
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'Homer',
                        "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
                        "phone": "555-222-1244"
                    }, 
                    {
                        'name': 'Marge',
                        "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                        "phone": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }
            ],
            listeners:[
                {
                    rowclick: function(a , record , element , rowIndex , e , eOpts) {
                        debugger;
                        if (rowIndex == 1)
                        {
                            alert("Hello");
                        }
                        else if (rowIndex == 2)
                        {
                            alert("Maddy");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            width: 200,
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Preview',
                    handler: function() {
                        var record = grid ? grid.getSelection()[0] : null;
                        if (!record)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        alert(record.get('name'));
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        grid.on("itemcontextmenu", function(grid, record, item, index, e) {
            e.stopEvent();
            contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
        });
    }
});
```

Can anybody please explain to me, why this is happening? My working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qg4)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Right Click on row one, you get preview in menu
2. Now click on row two. Ideally preview should disappear, but no it's not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an bug in version 5.1.0 (which is the version you are using in your fiddle).  It's fixed in version 5.1.1.  If you cannot update the version, try adding `contextMenu.hide()` in the `rowclick` handler.  If you want the contextMenu to disappear immediately, you will need to defer the rest of the handler.

Please see updated fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qi9).

Comment: Thanks for this answer